# Relation between the sign of the Stieltjes constants and some zero-free region of $\zeta$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

One may recall that the [Stieltjes constants $\gamma_{k}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) appear as the scaled coefficients in the regular part of the Laurent series expansion of the Riemann zeta function about $s = 1$:
$$
\begin{align} \zeta(s) 
= \frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} \gamma_{k}\:(s-1)^{k}, \quad  \,s \neq1, \tag1
\end{align}
$$ where $\displaystyle \gamma_{0}=\gamma$, the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Do you know some result/reference *connecting* the sign of the Stieltjes constants and some zero-free region of the Riemann zeta function?

The same question holds for the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) $\zeta(\cdot,a)$ and the [generalized Stieltjes constants $\gamma_{k}(a)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants#Generalized_Stieltjes_constants).

Comment: I think Jay Jorgenson and Lejla Smajlovic published an article about related results recently.

Comment: Sorry, the first author is not Jay Jorgenson but Almasa Odzak: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304006895_Euler-Stieltjes_constants_for_the_Rankin-Selberg_L-function_and_weighted_Selberg_orthogonality

Comment: @Sylvain JULIEN Thank you for the reference. I will try to understand their paper.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes I do. I've read different papers of Mark W. Coffey connecting somehow the Li constants to the Stieltjes constants. That's what I'm aware of. I was looking for others eventual papers. Thank you.

Comment: can you share some links ? (or explain what you understood :) )

Comment: @user1952009 I was thinking of: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0507042, https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0343, https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0345.